# Call PL SQL function with record type as input

Tags: oracle, plsql, mule

I have to call a PL SQL Function in Oracle DB with signature as given below:

```
FUNCTION funcName (input IN input_type) RETURN funcName_RETURN;
```

input_type is defined as below:

```
    create or replace TYPE       "INPUT_ROW"                                          AS OBJECT
 (
   Data1                VARCHAR2(255 BYTE),
   Data2                VARCHAR2(255 BYTE)
  )

 create or replace TYPE       "INPUT_TABLE"                                          
 AS VARRAY (50000) OF INPUT_ROW

 create or replace TYPE       "INPUT_TYPE"                                          AS OBJECT
 (
   file_date DATE,
   all_rows INPUT_TABLE
 )
```

I am trying to call this procedure from another pl sql block to insert data with multiple rows.

Comment: Where do you get these *"multiple rows"* from?

Comment: I want to invoke this Function from mule ESB.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how you want to call your function but let's assume it's in SQL:

```
select funcname( input_type (
             date '2019-02-05' -- file_date
             , input_table (
                 input_row('some val 1', 'another val 1')
                 ,  input_row('some val 2', 'another val 2')
                 )  -- all rows
            )  -- input     
     ) as funcname
from dual
```

This instantiates all the required objects with hard-coded values. Perhaps you want to pick them up from some table? If so, the principle is the same: instantiate each object from the pertinent data source.

Comment: Thanks a lot for a quick response. Appreciate!!